# UIButton to reset UIView

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 `UIViews`. One is the main menu the second one is the actual game. When it's game over, a Retry button appear, i want the button to reset the `UIView` so the game can start over. Right now i have the "Retry" button connected to the main menu but i don't like the fact that you gotta go by the main menu to retry.
I tried adding this line of code"

```
[GameViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

In my "GameOver" method but i had an error pointed to the `.view` and it said **"property view not found on object of type `GameViewController`".**

**EDIT**

GameViewController.h

```
int BirdFlight;
int RandomTopTunnelPostition;
int RandomBottomTunnelPosition;
int ScoreNumber;
NSInteger HighScoreNumber;

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIImageView *Bird;
IBOutlet UIButton *StartGame;
IBOutlet UIImageView *TunnelTop;
IBOutlet UIImageView *TunnelBottom;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Top;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Bottom;
IBOutlet UIButton *Exit;
IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;

NSTimer *BirdMovement;
NSTimer *TunnelMovement;

SystemSoundID PlaySoundID;
SystemSoundID PlaySoundID2;
SystemSoundID PlaySoundID3;

}
-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender;
-(void)BirdMoving;
-(void)TunnelMoving;
-(void)PlaceTunnels;
-(void)Score;
-(void)GameOver;

@end
```

Comment: does your instance is named GameViewController ? from the look of it you are trying to access a property directly from the class name which won't work

Comment: Yes it is named GameViewController. I placed [GameViewController.view setNeedsDisplay] in a method for the retry button. If retryButton isSelected { [GameViewController.view setNeedsDisplay] }. That's it.

Comment: can you post the definition of GameViewController along with its instance creation ?

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner, could you explain a bit more what you want me to post?

Comment: The code you wrote where you create the GameViewController and the header (.h) file of this controller

Comment: I posted an edit version with my full .h file

Comment: So you have some code like `GameViewController *GameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];`?

Comment: The GameViewController is just a UIViewController i dragged in the Storyboard. I don't have the kind of code you just mentionned.

Comment: can you post the code where you switch from the main menu to the game play ? I am guessing you are using segues so it will help if you post the code

Comment: I didn't use code to do that. I used the storyboard. There's a button on the main menu "Play game". I linked that button using Control with the game play UIView.